# How to post array form using LWP

Tags: perl, lwp

I am having problems creating an array that I can pass as a form using LWP. Basic code is

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
my %form = { };
$form->{'Submit'} = '1';
$form->{'Action'} = 'check';
for (my $i=0; $i<1; $i++) {
    $form->{'file_'.($i+1)} = [ './test.txt' ];
    $form->{'desc_'.($i+1)} = '';
}

$resp = $ua->post('http://someurl/test.php', 'Content_Type' => 'multipart/form-data'
, 'Content => [ \%form ]');

if ($resp->is_success()) {
    print "OK: ", $resp->content;
}
} else {
    print $claimid->as_string;
}
```

I guess I am not creating the form array correctly or using the wrong type as when I check the _POST variables in test.php nothing has been set :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that for some reason you've enclosed your form values in single quotes.  You want to send the data structure.  E.g.:

```
$resp = $ua->post('http://someurl/test.php', 
                  'Content_Type' => 'multipart/form-data',
                  'Content'      => \%form);
```

You want to either send the hash reference of `%form, not the has reference contained within an array reference as you had (`[ \%form ]`).   If you had wanted to send the data as an array reference, then you'd just use`[ %form ]` which populates the array with the key/value pairs from the hash.

I'd suggest that you read the [documentation for HTTP::Request::Common](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/HTTP-Message-6.02/lib/HTTP/Request/Common.pm), the POST section in particular for a cleaner way of doing this.

Comment: No dice :( I have dumped the data to check the array and that looks okay. { Action => "check", Submit => 1, file_1 => ["./test.txt"] } I have tried using $ua->request(POST $url, %form); If I simplify the test using $ua->request(POST $url, { 'Action' => 'test' }); that works fine.

Comment: @UxBoD - You're using a relative path for the file name, does it work if you give the full path to the file? `'/home/uxbod/test.txt'` instead of `'./test.txt'`

Comment: Nit: `->post` just passes its arguments to `POST`, so the latter isn't cleaner, it's the same.